# How to generate serialVersionUID for kotlin exceptions?

Tags: serialization, kotlin

As kotlin doesn't have static fields, should I define `serialVersionUID` in companion object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can declare it in the companion object. [The doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods-and-fields) says:

> Also, public properties defined in objects and companion objects, as well as top-level properties annotated with const, are turned into static fields in Java

But that seems to be the case with private properties too:

```
class MyException: Exception() {
    companion object {
        private val serialVersionUid: Long = 1
    }
}
```

> javap -c -p com.ninja_squad.kotlindiscovery.MyException.class

```
Compiled from "MyException.kt"
public final class com.ninja_squad.kotlindiscovery.MyException extends java.lang.Exception {
  private static final long serialVersionUid;

  public static final com.ninja_squad.kotlindiscovery.MyException$Companion Companion;

  static {};
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #38                 // Field com/ninja_squad/kotlindiscovery/MyException$Companion.INSTANCE:Lcom/ninja_squad/kotlindiscovery/MyException$Companion;
       3: putstatic     #40                 // Field Companion:Lcom/ninja_squad/kotlindiscovery/MyException$Companion;
       6: lconst_1      
       7: putstatic     #21                 // Field serialVersionUid:J
      10: return        

  public com.ninja_squad.kotlindiscovery.MyException();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #15                 // Method java/lang/Exception."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static final long access$getSerialVersionUid$cp();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #21                 // Field serialVersionUid:J
       3: lreturn       
}
```

Comment: It's not `serialVersionUid` but `serialVersionUID`. Better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539809/1749411

Answer (score 24):

To create the `serialVersionUID` for a class in Kotlin you have a few options all involving adding a member to the companion object of the class.

**The most concise bytecode** comes from a `private const val` which will become a private static variable on the containing class, in this case `MySpecialCase`:

```
class MySpecialCase : Serializable {
    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID: Long = 123
    }
}
```

You can also use these forms, **each with a side effect of having getter/setter methods** which are not necessary for serialization...

```
class MySpecialCase : Serializable {
    companion object {
        private val serialVersionUID: Long = 123
    }
}
```

This creates the static field but also creates a getter as well `getSerialVersionUID` on the companion object which is unnecessary.

```
class MySpecialCase : Serializable {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic private val serialVersionUID: Long = 123
    }
}
```

This creates the static field but also creates a static getter as well `getSerialVersionUID` on the containing class `MySpecialCase` which is unnecessary.

But all work as a method of adding the `serialVersionUID` to a `Serializable` class.

Comment: `@JvmStatic` has effect on methods only (namely getter and setter of a property) and not on fields. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods

Comment: Yep, was just noting the different methods and what happens when you use them.  side effect of causing getter/setters, and where those end up.

Comment: I added more clarity around that topic.

Comment: I mean it's no matter whether `@JvmStatic` present or not, to have the field generated, so it's completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: It is a common answer people have given for this problem and I list it under those that have a side effect and what that side effect is, so maybe people will understand they don't need the other version.  If i omit the other version and don't say why, they may continue to use it for no reason.

Comment: You can remove the type and just add the "L" at the number like this:
`private const val serialVersionUID = 123L`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin [GenerateSerialVersionUID](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13497-generateserialversionuid) to automatically generate the serialVersionUID field.

Since Kotlin language does not support static, you need to use the const decoration in the generated companion object (of course, it is also possible to use the `@JvmField` annotation).