# Locking down the serialVersionUID in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've been battling the whole morning to lock down the `serialVersionUID` in a Kotlin class. I have a `BaseModel` which is extended by `Project`

```
abstract class BaseModel<T>(
        var id: Int? = null,
        private val fileName: String,
        private val data: MutableList<T>,
        private val indices: MutableMap<Int, T>
) : Serializable {

  ...

   protected fun writeToDisk() {
       val oos = ObjectOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(fetchFileName()))   )
       oos.writeObject(fetchData());
       oos.close();
   }


}
```

And the project class:

```
class Project(
        var name: String = "",
        var repo: String = ""

) : BaseModel<Project>(
        data = Data.projects,
        indices = Data.projectsIndex,
        fileName = "data/projects.dat"
), Serializable {

    ...

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Project: id=${id}, name=${name}, repo=${repo}"
    }

}
```

Every time I write to Disk and then change anything in the class and try to read it back again, I would get:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: com.jvaas.bob.model.Project; local
>   class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID =
>   4156405178259085766, local class serialVersionUID =
>   2024101567466310467

I've tried adding:

```
private val serialVersionUID: Long = 1
```

to all classes with no effect.

Some examples on StackOverflow were using `serialVersionUid` which had no effect either (I believe this is intelliJ lowercasing the last two letters for some reason)

`@JvmStatic` doesn't work here since it's not an `object`, I've tried making it non-private with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate serialVersionUID for kotlin exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241816/how-to-generate-serialversionuid-for-kotlin-exceptions)

Comment: **Now documented in:** https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/kotlin/2273/idioms/23147/serializable-and-serialversionuid-in-kotlin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define `serialVersionUID` as a constant in a companion object:

```
abstract class BaseModel<T> : Serializable {
    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID: Long = -1
    }
}
```

Constants are compiled to fields, and fields of a companion are stored as static fields of the class that contains companion. Therefore you get what you need – a private static field `serialVersionUID` in your serializable class.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was actually much simpler than I thought, use a companion object. This now serializes perfectly and if I add more fields, it still serializes to disk and deserializes unless I change the `serialVersionUID`

Base:

```
abstract class BaseModel<T>(
        var id: Int? = null,
        private val fileName: String,
        private val data: MutableList<T>,
        private val indices: MutableMap<Int, T>
) : Serializable {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic private val serialVersionUID: Long = 1
    }

    ...

}
```

Project:

```
class Project(
        var name: String = "",
        var repo: String = ""

) : BaseModel<Project>(
        data = Data.projects,
        indices = Data.projectsIndex,
        fileName = "data/projects.dat"
), Serializable {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic private val serialVersionUID: Long = 1
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Project: id=${id}, name=${name}, repo=${repo}"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin: [GenerateSerialVersionUID](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13497-generateserialversionuid/versions)，use plugin to auto generate default serial version uid，usage: [Click here](https://github.com/yuanhoujun/intellij-generate-serial-version-uid-plugin).